# Incandescent light bulb lifetime - exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, physics

It's been said that incandescent light bulbs lifetime has exponential distribution. As I understand, this means a 10,000 hours time-to-failure has the same probability no matter how long the light bulb was used until now (i.e. the "memorylessness" property).

On the other hand, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Voltage.2C_light_output.2C_and_lifetime) that "(a light bulb's) Lifetime is approximately proportional to $V^{−16}$". Doesn't this mean that if the lifetime is 10,000 hours and 5,000 hours have passed, failure in 10,000 hours is less likely than in 5,000 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not expect light bulbs to have an exponential distribution, as there is a wear out mechanism involved-evaporation of the filament material.  The Wikipedia statement that the lifetime is proportional to $V^{-16}$ is for steady state conditions.  Higher voltage leads to higher operating temperature, which leads to increased evaporation.  "Long-life" bulbs have cooler filaments, as you can see because they generate less (and redder) light for the same power consumption.  All this ignores the stresses generated in on/off cycles, and the fact that the power when the bulb is turned on is much higher than steady state due to the lower resistance at lower temperature.