# Why the life of a light bulb follow an exponential law?

Tags: probability

Why the life of a light bulb follow an exponential law ? My teacher always said that, but he can't explain why it's this. So why did we decided that a light bulb follow an exponential law ? Where does this fact comes from ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478820/exponential-bulbs

Comment: Why do we think that a coin shows heads just as often as tails and that subsequent coin tosses (or tosses with different coins) are independent? In the end, all we can do is check by extended experiments whether our simple expectations match the real world with sufficient accuracy ...

Comment: A related question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39539/incandescent-light-bulb-lifetime-exponential-distribution?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

The exponential distribution comes from the assumption that light bulbs do not age. They just randomly, for each moment in time, decide whether to fail or to keep working, with the same probability regardless of how old they are. This leads to the exponential distribution.

Is this the way light bulbs actually works? I have no idea, but since this is such a ubiquitous example I would at the very least find it reasonable that it's *close* to the truth. Someone probably checked it once a long time ago, and it's just been the established truth since.

Comment: "The exponential distribution comes from the assumption that light bulbs do not age." **Questions :** But why a bulb light would be memoryless ? How can you justify this ? It looks a bit magic and coming from nowhere :) Also, why memoryless gives exponential law ? Is it the only law that is memoryless ? (thank you)

Comment: @user623855 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness says exponential is the only one, yes. And did you read the second paragraph of my answer? I have no idea whether it's actually true that lightbulbs work that way. It's just a very common example in probability exercises.

Comment: Yes I did don't worry :) It's just strange for me to say that bulb light works like that without proof... (even if it's a common exercise of probability). It sounds a bit as : Let say that Riemann conjecture is true... :-D

Comment: @user623855 Many theorems start with "Assume the Riemann hypothesis is true. Then ..." Why would it be bad to say "Assume lightbulbs are memoryless. Then ..."?

Answer (score 3):

The Exponential distribution describes the interval between events of a Possion process, in which events occur *continuously* and *independently* at a *constant* average rate.   One of the key properties of this is that this random variable is *memoryless*.   Eg: the time until failure is independent of any previous amount of operational time.

It is basically a continuous analogue of the Geometric distribution, which describes the count until first failure in a sequence of trials with independent and identical Bernoulli success rate.

The exponetial distribution is used to model various component decay processes, where the causes of failure are esentially unpredictable save that they occur continuously, *seemingly* independently, and at an *apparent* average rate.

Comment: But why a bulb light would be memoryless ? How can you justify this ? It looks a bit magic and coming from nowhere :) Also, why memoryless gives exponential law ? Is it the only law that is memoryless ? (thank you)

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that a bulb's life follows an exponential distribution in Real Life.  The assumption of an exponential distribution is one of those assumptions that authors of textbooks make in order to have a problem with an easy analytical solution.

Consider the following.  Suppose the bulb's life has an exponential distribution with a mean life of 1 year.  You have a bulb which has lasted 1 year.  How much life remains?  On average, 1 year.  Do you believe this?

** Edited 30 June: Changed example of bulb life in example from 100 hours to a more realistic 1 year.

Comment: Given that people have notoriously bad intuition about probability -- and specifically about processes where the distribution remains unchanged over time -- credulity is a pretty poor indicator of truth.

Comment: Whether one believes it has nothing to do with reality. Have you actually gone out and _measured_ it? Take a bunch of light bulbs, note how many die the first 100 hours. Then among those who lived, note how many die the next 100 hours. And so on. If you find that the proportion of light bulbs which dies within a given 100 hour window changes significantly from window to window, then you can say that it doesn't fit with real life. Me, I find it likely that they follow an exponential distribution; not much happens inside a lightbulb, so the assumption that they do not age seems reasonable.

Comment: This was asked on stats.SE (without answer): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228241/can-the-exponential-distribution-actually-be-used-to-model-light-bulbs-lifetime

Comment: A better question might be whether the exponential model of bulb life is useful. Supposedly it was George E.P. Box who said, "All models are wrong, but some are useful."

Answer (score 0):

This was a great question, one I suffered with for a while.  If you accept the premise that a lightbulb can be modeled by a memoryless exponential function, then you are forced to accept some rather embarrassing results.

For instance, let's say you have $2$ lightbulbs, each modeled by a memoryless exponential with a mean of $30$ minutes.  An experiment is done where the first bulb is run until it fails, the $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ one is immediately put in and let run to it fails and you record only the time of the $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ bulbs failure, let's say $60$ minutes.  Using Bayesian Inference, you want to use the time the  $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ bulb failed to update you knowledge about when the $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ bulb failed. With Baye's Rule it is straight forward to show that you've learned nothing, that the failure of the $1^{\mathrm{st}}$ bulb is just as likely to have been at one second in, $59$ minutes in, or its mean, $30$ minutes in.  This is preposterous, and if you apply this to bulbs or even, worse bridges, you are making a big mistake.

A coin flip is memoryless, the arrival of a single photon in a very low light environment is memoryless, not a lightbulb, because a lightbulb failure is not a single event, but rather a series of events where material is slowly lost from the filament finally leading to failure, and it cannot be modeled with a memoryless distribution.  I wish they would stop using lightbulbs as the cannonical example of exponential distributions and Bayesian Inference.

Comment: What is your question?